# Performance issue with Java2D gradients and iText PDF

Tags: performance, pdf, itext, java-2d, linear-gradients

I am using iText PDF 5.4 along with the Java2D interface (`java.awt.Graphics` canvas), and I have a severe problem with **gradients**.

I am painting many rectangular shapes whose paint is a `LinearGradientPaint`. This results in **large files** (e.g., 10 MB), and trying to open the results in e.g. `Preview.app` brings the computer **to total halt**. The problem seems to be memory usage, because the first dozens of boxes paint rather quickly and then performance slows down somewhat linearly with more boxes, which means that for a typical page it takes >10 minutes to open.

Adobe Acrobat is also slow but at least it takes some 4 or 5 seconds instead of several minutes.

---

Is this a bug of iText? Is there a **setting** or **tweak** in iText that controls the representation of gradients? I guess it decomposes them into hundreds of separate paint commands instead of using a direct gradient component (if that exists—I know it exists in SVG, but PDF I have no clue).

The condition is that I stay in the `awt.Graphics`, I cannot rewrite my rendering code to not use Java2D.

Comment: When using iText's "native PDF" functionality, you can often create a complex graphical object in only a handful of lines. When using `java.awt.Graphics`, iText has to obey the plethora of instructions triggered by the `Graphics` class in Java. I wouldn't call this an iText bug; you've made an architectural choice and you now pay the price for that choice.

Comment: So are you saying, there is no way to improve the representation of Java2D gradients? I totally understand that the direct objects will be more efficient, but I am typically having Swing GUIs and no resources to develop every graphical structure twice.

Comment: Well, if you can't change the way `java.awt.Graphics2D`, then the only way would be to completely re-engineer iText's `PdfGraphics2D`. We're not going to do that. We've always advised to use native PDF and only resort to `PdfGraphics2D` in case native PDF isn't possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative idea would be to use [Apache Batik](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/) and output to SVG instead. There is [an example](http://www.udel.edu/CIS/software/dist/batik-1.6/docs/svggen.html) that shows how to enable the correct transcoding of `LinearGradientPaint` to the SVG equivalent.

**EDIT**: There seems to be a new Java2D-to-SVG library [JFreeSVG](http://www.jfree.org/jfreesvg/). Recent changes indicate that gradients are implemented.